# What's the difference between Fourier Cosine and Sine Series besides the periodic function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I'm aware for Fourier Cosine Series you have an even extension of f(x) and the Sine Series has an odd extension, the former requiring `a_o`, `a_n`, and cosine as the periodic function, with the latter containing `b_n` with sine as the periodic function.  However, can't any function be translated to either its sine or cosine series equivalent?  Why bother learning both methods?  Is there some inherent difference that I'm not recognizing?  If anything, shouldn't you always just calculate the sine series for every f(x) since you only have to compute one coefficient (`b_n`)?

It's really baffling and I can't find any articles online describing the obvious differences or advantages/disadvantages to either method.

Thanks!

Comment: Not all functions are odd or even. There are functions that are neither.

Comment: they are not "even/odd extensions" of a function, if the function is even (alt. odd) then it Fourier series have sine (alt. cosine) coefficients with value zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, can't any function be translated to either its sine or cosine series equivalent?

No.

Recall that a linear combination of even functions is even, and a linear combination of any odd functions is odd. That means neither class is sufficient to represent functions that are neither even nor odd.

Now, what *is* true is that [any function can be written as **a sum of** an even *and* an odd function](/q/1367296/4890), so you can decompose the even parts in terms of cosine, the odd parts in terms of sine, and add them up to get the Fourier series.

Comment: I agree with part of the first paragraph.  However, my book claims it can create both a Sine Series and a Cosine Series for f(x) = e^x .  In this case, f(x) is neither odd or even, but after calculation of the Sine and Cosine Series, you have two different forms/equations/approximations of f(x) in terms of sine and cosine, respectively.

Comment: Are you supposed to calculate the Sine and Cosine Series for a given function (e.g. f(x) = e^x) and then combine them together to get the actual Fourier Series?

Comment: @Bob: Is your book doing this in a particular interval (say, (0,L))? If so that would explain it because then it doesn't matter what happens for, say, negative inputs.

Comment: Yeah, it's on the interval [0, 1]

Comment: @Bob: Okay well that's very important :-) in that case you can imagine that what you're really doing is finding the sine series for a *different* function whose behavior for positive $x$ is $e^x$, but whose behavior for negative $x$ is $-e^{-x}$. *Then* you can find the sine series for *that* function. This is possible because the function is now odd. But since you're looking only at its behavior for positive $x$, it will give you what you want for $e^x$, since its behavior matches that of $e^x$.

Comment: That makes sense!  So if it's on a specific interval [0, L], you can use the Sine OR Cosine Series as an approximation.  But if it's on [-L, L], you have to compute the complete Fourier Series (with both cosine and sine in the summation) with `a_n`, `b_n`, and `a_0` on the entire interval?

Comment: @Bob: Yes, but to be more precise: if it's on an interval such that there exists an *extension* of the function beyond that interval that could make the function odd (/even), then you can approximate the function's behavior over that interval with a sine (/cosine) series, since it's equivalent to approximating the hypothetically-extended function. Otherwise, you'll need both sines and cosines, assuming a decomposition exists at all.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That clarifies it a lot more.  I was thinking this whole time they had different use cases :P .  I appreciate :)

Comment: @Bob: Yeah, no problem :) it sounds easy in hindsight but I know from first-hand experience it's not at *all* obvious before somebody finally explains it to you!

Comment: One more thing to add is that one extension may give you a continuous function, whereas the other may not (e.g. the even extension of $x^2$ is continuous, the odd one isn't). This can affect things like how quickly the Fourier Series converges, which is important in applications (in the case of $x^2$, the cosine series has coefficients that are $O(1/k^2)$, while those of the sine series are only $O(1/k)$).

Comment: @Chappers: Is that a typo? I'm pretty sure both the even and odd extensions of $x^2$ are continuous...

Comment: They are at zero, but not at the other endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The cosine series captures the even part of a function

$$f_{e}(x) = \dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$$

The sine series captures the odd part of a function

$$f_{o}(x) = \dfrac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$

And one can encounter functions for which you can never have a purely even or purely odd function, no matter how the function is shifted, e.g.

$$f(x) = cos(x) + sin(x)$$

So you need both to handle any possible function you might encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function graphed here:

[image]

This function is neither odd nor even.
Moreover, you cannot translate it to make it odd or to make it even.

In general you need both cosine and sine terms, not just one or the other.
The even and odd functions are the exceptional cases.

Comment: I would say this function is definitely odd. =P